# Copy the string in the file repeatedly based on the parameter

Tags: python-3.x

In the below snippet, I need to copy

```
    {
        @@,
        @$,
        @%,
        $$ 
    }
```

several times based on PARAMETER.

For Eg:
If PARAMETER is 2, In the file, Code should look like as mentioned below when opened

```
    const ABC ARR[PARAMETER] =
    {
        {
            @@,
            @$,
            @%,
            $$
        },
        {
            @@,
            @$,
            @%,
            $$
        }  
    };
```

I have to write a test code in Python.

Comment: Note: I have to write a code in python, to auto-generate the Configuration file based on number of Parameter. If PARAMETER = 3, then one more snippet should get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to generate the code.

```py
PARAMETER = 3
'const ABC ARR[' + str(PARAMETER) + '] = {' + ("{ @@, @$, @%, $$ }, " * PARAMETER)[:-2] + '}'
```

**Output**:

> 'const ABC ARR[3] = {{ @@, @$, @%, $$ }, { @@, @$, @%, $$ }, { @@, @$, @%, $$ }}'